# I'm having trouble getting information from database to chart within view

Tags: c#

I'm building a page with a morris chart displaying two sets of parameters: the amount of money that has been budgeted and the amount that was actually spent. I need to add all transactions for a particular budget as well as all the individual items on that budget and display them next to each other as bars. I'm getting the budget amount to display just fine, but the actual spend amount only displays for one budget set - the other just shows 0. Here's some of what's in my controller:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var household = db.Users.Find(userId).MyHouse;
var dataSet = new List<ChartData>();

foreach (var budget in household.Budget.ToList())
{
    var data = new ChartData
    {
        Label = budget.Name,
        Budget = budget.Items.Select(i => i.Amount).Sum(),
        Spent = db.BudgetItems
            .FirstOrDefault(b => b.BudgetId == budget.Id).Transactions
            .Select(t => t.Purchase).Sum()
    };
    dataSet.Add(data);
}
```

Label shows the name of the budget set under the chart. Budget shows the bar with the estimated amount. Spent should show the bar with the actual amount spent.

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019). We can't do this for you. At a first glance, there is no logical error in your code, but we cannot inspect the values.

Comment: Could you please check your data in database first, there are might be no 'transactions' for other households

Comment: There is data in the db for both of the current ones.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!